# Pinia store (composition api) modify route

Tags: firebase, vuejs3, vue-router, pinia

I am using:

```
vue@3.2.47
pinia@2.0.35
vue-router@4.1.6
```

I have created a store for the authentication with a firebase db. The code is as follow:

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword,signInWithEmailAndPassword,signOut,onAuthStateChanged  } from "firebase/auth";
import { auth } from "@/firebase";

export const useStoreAuth = defineStore('storeAuth', {
  state: () => {
    return {
      user: null,
    }
  },
  actions: {
    init() {
      onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {      
        if (user) {
          this.user = {}
          this.user.id = user.uid
          this.user.email = user.email
        } else {
          this.user = null
        }
      });
    },
    registerUser(credentials) {
      createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, credentials.email, credentials.password).then((userCredential) => {
        const user = userCredential.user 
        this.router.push('/')     
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log('Error while registering:',error.message);
        }
      });
    },...
```

I am using this.router.push in order to go to the home page after successful registration.

I would like to rewrite my code using the composition API but when I do, I don't understand how to rewrite my code so that the function registerUser(credentials) can use this.router.push.

I have tried to rewrite it like this:

```
const registerUser = (credentials) => {
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, credentials.email, credentials.password).then((userCredential) => {
      const firebaseUser = userCredential.user 
      router.push('/')     
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log('Error while registering:',error.message);
      }
    });
  }
```

but it is not working in this case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass router as an argument of registerUser()

In your component

```
import { useRouter } from "vue-router";
const router = useRouter();
...
registerUser(credentials, router);
```

In your store

```
const registerUser = (credentials, router) => {
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, credentials.email, credentials.password).then((userCredential) => {
      const firebaseUser = userCredential.user 
      router.push('/')     
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log('Error while registering:',error.message);
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

in composition api, you can use router with useRouter

```
import { useRouter } from "vue-router";

const router = useRouter();

...andyourcode...
```

see this [page](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#Functions-useRouter) , official vue router site.